GoogleOAuth snippet results in hydration error
I am following the instructions in a new project to use Supabase to handle my auth. I first installed the NextJS supabase template.  Then I try to add the Google OAuth custom snippet, as recommended in step #4 documentation
// app/page.tsx
import { GoogleOAuth } from '@/components/googleOAuth';

export default async function Index() {
  return (
    <main className="flex-1 flex flex-col gap-6 px-4">
      <div>
        <h2>Please sign in</h2>
        <GoogleOAuth />
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}

export const GoogleOAuth = () => {
  const url = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID;
  return (
    <>
      <div
        id="g_id_onload"
        data-client_id={url}
        data-context="signin"
        data-ux_mode="popup"
        data-callback="handleSignInWithGoogle"
        data-itp_support="true"
      />
      <div
        className="g_id_signin"
        data-type="standard"
        data-shape="pill"
        data-theme="filled_black"
        data-text="signin_with"
        data-size="large"
        data-logo_alignment="left"
      />
    </>
  );
};

However, this results in a quick flash of the Google LoginButton followed by the app error message:

Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server...Did not expect server HTML to contain a <div> in <div>.

<Index>
  <main>
    <div>
    ^^^^^
      <GoogleOAuth>
        <GoogleOAuth>
          <div>
          ^^^^^

I also tried adding use client to the top of the GoogleOAuth component, but no change. I also tried killing & restarting the server.
Any ideas to use this snippet for Google OAuth?
